# Search in a modal, update DIV on original page

Tags: php, ajax, bootstrap-modal

It's another late night and another seemingly simple issue that's causing a headache!

So, here's the situation.  I have a simple HTML form that's in a Bootstrap modal.  When this form is submitted, there's an AJAX POST to a receiving page, SESSIONS are set and the request is then forwarded to a simple DB query.  This all works.

What I want to do is show the sessions on the original page without a page refresh.

I thought this would be easy so I tried using this on the original page;

```
 $('#filteroptions').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
 $("#breadcrumbs").load('includes/files/private/breadcrumb.php'); 
 });
```

breadcrumb.php holds the output format and the file is populated immediately after the POST from the modal (called filteroptions)

I also tried to attach it to the POST success with a simple success process to load the file but each time, the breadcrumb.php fils to be loaded.

Curiously, if I ctrl+F5 the page after the first POST, there is no value shown BUT if I search again the DIV is updated each time I search after that.

Why would the request not fire the first time that the search is performed?  Why do I need to refresh the page for everything to start working?

There is no caching to it's not a case of a dependantr file being cached after the refresh.

Thanks

Comment: Did you check for errors in network panel of browser's developer console?

Comment: Hi Arvind, the console shows what I would expect and there are no errors. There's also nothing in the network log to suggest that there was an attempt to load breadcrumb.php until after the CTRL+F5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to populate the div with nothing and then update it.

Previously, the div was only being drawn when it was populated thanks to the code in the breadcrumb file looking for a specific POST or SESSION variable.

It now allows for a blank value.